# Logistics Regression + Variance

Tags: probability-distributions, variance, regression-analysis, logistic-regression

I'm having an issue with this problem of Logistics Model and Variance of the OR estimator as I don't know if I can still reducing it. This is what I have done:

/ We know that the odds ratio associated to Xj is constant: OR = exp(Bj). Explain how to determine the variance of the OR estimator: var(exp(Bj)). /

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D6R8.jpg]

Using the delta rule I've done this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D6R8.jpg]

However I don't know if this can be reduced even more to get a simpler solution.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a certain $j$, $e^{\hat{\beta}_j}$ is scalar, so using the "Delta" method (i.e., second order Taylor expansion at $\beta_j$) you have 
$$
e^{\hat{\beta}_j} = e^{{\beta}_j} + e^{{\beta}_j}(\hat{\beta}_j - {\beta}_j) + o_p(r_n),
$$ 
hence, by (1) neglecting the remainder, (2) taking $e^{\beta_j}$ to the LHS and (3) squaring you get
$$
( e^{\hat{\beta}_j} - e^{{\beta}_j})^2
 \approx
  e^{2{\beta}_j}(\hat{\beta}_j - {\beta}_j)^2,
$$
taking an expectation of both sides, you have 
$$
\mathbb{E}( e^{\hat{\beta}_j} - e^{{\beta}_j})^2 \approx 
\operatorname{Var}( e^{\hat{\beta}_j})\approx 
 e^{2{\beta}_j}
\operatorname{Var}(\hat{\beta}_j ).
$$

Another possible approximation is using the fact that $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\beta}_j - \beta_j) \xrightarrow{D}\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2) $, hence for large enough sample $\hat{\beta}_j$ is approximately normal, thus
$$
e^{\hat{\beta}_j} \sim _{approx}\text{LogNormal}(\beta, \sigma^2),
$$
hence its variance is approximately $(e^{\sigma^2} - 1) e^{2\beta_j +\sigma^2}$.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!